# Smartgwt form's item

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-platform

I am developing a website using both Smartgwt and GWTP. 
When tesing with IE8, I click on some form items which have some button on it, like SelectItem, ColorPickerItem and DateItem, it will lead me to the default page. For example if i am on 
    http://127.0.0.1:8888/mypage.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#!somepage
, then I click on those items on this page, the address will become
    http://127.0.0.1:8888/mypage.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#

But when I use Chrome, then there is no problem.

Could any one tell me what is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in GWTP - it suggests that they are adding anchors to all `<a>` elements anywhere on the page, or adding event handlers to all such elements, including ones rendered by SmartGWT.